# c++ debugging a recursive function and it doesn't exit the function right away

Tags: c++

If I put a break point on this function it will step through until the base case is met but when it hits the return 1 it doesn't actually exit the loop. Instead it goes to the bottom bracket and then bounces to int t = expo(m, n / 2) and steps downs to return t * t*m. It then goes back to the bottom bracket and repeats this process before eventually stopping. Can someone explain what is going on?

```
int expo(const int m, const unsigned int n) {

    funcCallCounter++;  //counts how many times the function is called

    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            int t = expo(m, n / 2);
            return t * t;
        }
        else {
            int t = expo(m, n / 2);
            return t * t*m;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: The value supplied for m & n is 2 & 15.

Comment: What's going on is recursion. You're witnessing the miracle of recursion. Upon returning from a recursed-to function, execution resumes at where the previous level of recursion was.

Comment: So this is not some kind of infinite loop?

Comment: When I run it the return value for parameters specified is 32768. Don't know if that is the answer you expect, but the recursion is working.

Comment: There may or may not be an infinite loop, but what you've described is, precisely, recursion at work.

Comment: When I witnessed this phenomena I thought maybe it was a problem but it sounds like this is exactly what I want to see.

Comment: @Richard using the funcCallCounter it says It take 5 recursive call to take 2^15. One thing I am wondering is that it might be hitting the base case to soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the flow of your program in a function encounters a `return` statement, control is returned to place that called that function. That is true even if it was the same function. This is completely normal and expected.

In your case, each call still has work to do *after* the recursive step (because your `expo()` call is never quite the last thing before `return`) and you're seeing the program get on with that work.

Keep an eye on your *stack frame* while debugging; you'll see that it's not really jumping around in the way that you think it is; you're returning to previous call contexts.